# Rename files while copying

Tags: sftp, scp, file-rename

In our unix server, the 'myfolder' contains many archive folders appended by date

```
archive.2012-04-10
archive.2012-04-11
```

Each archive folder contains a zipped file like below

```
my_transaction.log-20120410.gz
```

I know that the below one command will copy my_transaction.log-20120410.gz, my_transaction.log-20120411.gz and my_transaction.log-20120412.gz and put it under /tmp folder under 'serverip' server.

```
scp /myfolder/archive.2012-04-1[0-2]/my_transaction* username@serverip:/tmp
```

My question has two parts

1)What would be the one line command if I wanted to copy my_transaction.log-20120409.gz as well along with the above?

2)What would be the command to copy and rename the copied files under /tmp folder. That is it should be copied as below under /tmp. I would like to add an _1 with transaction while copied to 'serverip' /tmp folder.

```
my_transaction_1.log-20120409.gz
my_transaction_1.log-20120410.gz
my_transaction_1.log-20120411.gz
my_transaction_1.log-20120412.gz
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first point, try [extended globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing): (untested)

```
# This could go in your ~/.bashrc
shopt -s extglob
scp /myfolder/archive.2012-04-@(09|1[0-2])/my_transaction* username@serverip:/tmp
```

For the second point, I don't think you can both scp and rename all the files in one go. You could do them all in a loop, though. E.g. (also untested)

```
for file in /myfolder/archive.2012-04-@(09|1[0-2])/my_transaction*; do
    newfile=$( echo $file | sed -e "s/my_transaction/my_transaction_1/")
    # Take out the "echo" if the command looks OK
    echo scp $newfile username@serverip:/tmp
done
```

Comment: for renaming and copying can we use sftp? I am not specifically looking for scp.

Comment: I don't think that would make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I did find one solution for the same problem, please see:

```
scp -v localhost:/home/myuser/test/arquivo* .  2>&1| grep -i modes|awk '{print $6}'
```

This will get the filename that was transfered by scp, since you have each name you can use the awk for rename after each file more or less in this way:

```
scp -v localhost:/home/myuser/test/arquivo* .  2>&1| grep -i modes|awk '{print "mv "$6" "$6".renamed"}'|sh -x
```

I hope that this will help you too.
For me is working very well.